# How to disable debug messages in android project?

Tags: android

we have a big project cant delete lot of debug messages and project is in release stage.we want to disable all debug messages in our projects.the debug message format is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("Gajanand", "onCreate: just check");
}
```

i tried with

```
Android:debuggable="false"
```

but its not working
and also tried to change build variant to release but getting many errors not able to build project
.please any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following proguard-rule in order to ignore all Debug and Verbose Logs in a release:

```
# ignore all Debug and Verbose Logs in a release
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

So you dont have to "disable" all your Logs manually - they get just obfuscated.

In order to apply this proguard rule you have to use the optimization function of proguard by modifying your gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        proguardFile '/<your-custom-file>/app/proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

Also have a look in the proguard manual:
https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage

Comment: did you change your gradle file? Why is it not working? - Can you show us the problem?

Comment: i was facing issues in  signingConfig signingConfigs.config this line was not detecting ..by using build variants it detected...any how problem resolved..and i removed  proguardFile '/<your-custom-file>/app/proguard-rules.pro' line ..thanks..

Answer (score 1):

For my project I was able to get rid of the debug messages with the following.

1. First I went to the **proguard-rules.pro** file that should be near your build.gradle file. In that file I added:

   **-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** **d(...);**
   **}**
2. Then I went to the build.gradle file and added:

   `buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
           'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }`

For more info go [here](https://support.brightcove.com/removing-android-log-messages).

Answer (score 0):

you can do the hard way and use remplace
 " Ctr + shift + r "
 and remplace all the 
"log." by " // " 
to put in comment all the log request.